# How do you sync your branch with origin/branch after rebase?

Tags: git, github

Every time I checkout "develop" branch, git pull, checkout my local branch, and `git rebase develop`, it applies a growing list of changes that have already been applied before, such that the terminal output reads something like :

`Your branch and 'origin/branch' have diverged,
and have 26 and 24 different commits each, respectively. 
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)`

I don't want to `git pull` because it will pull old changes and cause merge conflicts and every time I `git push -f`, it seems my local branch is back up to date with origin/branch, until this all happens again.

As you can probably already tell, I am not super familar with git, but I have the feeling that my local branch needs to be set as the current HEAD, maybe?

What can I do to sync my local branch and origin/branch such that future git rebase's doesn't continue applying old changes?

Comment: rebase rewrites history. Seems like you're rewriting a history you already pushed - don't do that.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks, so how do I correct this and properly rebase in the future?

Comment: Why do you want to rebase? You probably want to merge rather than rebase.

Comment: @tkausl I read that rebasing is cleaner in terms of less commit messages - do you always merge and not rebase?

Comment: Less commits isn't necessarily cleaner - usually rebase should only ever be used on private/local branches or PRs.

Comment: @tkausl Ok, thanks for your help. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I correct this and properly rebase in the future?

If you keep rebasing commit that were already pushed, you will end up with the same issue.
For a feature or fix branch though, where you are the only one, this is not a big deal, and a `push -f` is enough.